# How to preview picked image on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

how to preview an image is to be chosen from gallery or camera in flutter with the new version of image_picker where

```
PickedFile image = await _picker.getImage(...)
```

is replace with

```
final XFile? photo = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
```

so photo must be displayed when it is selected properly

Comment: What you;ve tried so far to show the image?

Comment: yes display it when succeded to load

Comment: use Image.file(
   photo
  )

Comment: its not file its XFIle , diffrent

Comment: use `Image.memory`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using dialog in flutter.

Here is how I dealt with it.

```
onLongPress: () {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) {
            final width = ctx.getWidth(1);
            final height = ctx.getHeight(1);
            return AlertDialog(
              content: Stack(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: width * 0.9,
                    height: height * 0.7,
                    child: Image.network(
                      food.imageUrl,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle),
                        child: Icon(
                          CupertinoIcons.xmark_circle,
                          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                          size: 40,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            );
          },
        );
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can preview image which you select from gallery or camera as below :

```
Image.file(
        File("file path will be here"), // You can access it with . operator and path property
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

convert to file:

```
File newPhoto = File(photo.path);
```

Use:

```
Image.file(newPhoto);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used image_pickers package much easier

```
 late File imageFile = File("");
  bool isloaded = false;

  ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => pickImageFromCamera(),)

Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: !isloaded
                        ? Image.network(
                            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/No_image_available.svg/2048px-No_image_available.svg.png")
                        : Image.file(imageFile)),

void pickImageFromCamera() async {
    List<Media>? res = await ImagesPicker.openCamera(
      pickType: PickType.image,
    );
    print(res);
    if (res != null) {
      print(res[0].path);
      setState(() {
        imageFile = File(res[0].path);
        isloaded = true;
        setState(() {});
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isloaded = false;
      });
    }
  }
```